# Urban Airship push notification is not pushing the data

Tags: android, urbanairship.com

I am new to urban airship, and integrating this to my Android application. Got sample source from Airship, and i followed same procedure in order to invoke airship into my application. but whenever i send push notification, i cant get it through my device. The package name what i given in my source same i gave in Airship. can anyone guide me how to integrate the Urban Airship in android application.

```
   AirshipConfigOptions options = AirshipConfigOptions.loadDefaultOptions(this);

    // Optionally, customize your config at runtime:
    //
    // options.inProduction = false;
     options.developmentAppKey = "My Key";
     options.developmentAppSecret "My key";

    UAirship.takeOff(this, options);
    Logger.logLevel = Log.VERBOSE;

    //use CustomPushNotificationBuilder to specify a custom layout
    CustomPushNotificationBuilder nb = new CustomPushNotificationBuilder();

    nb.statusBarIconDrawableId = R.drawable.icon_small;//custom status bar icon

    nb.layout = R.layout.notification;
    nb.layoutIconDrawableId = R.drawable.icon;//custom layout icon
    nb.layoutIconId = R.id.icon;
    nb.layoutSubjectId = R.id.subject;
    nb.layoutMessageId = R.id.message;

    // customize the sound played when a push is received
    //nb.soundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+this.getPackageName()+"/" +R.raw.cat);

    PushManager.shared().setNotificationBuilder(nb);
    PushManager.shared().setIntentReceiver(IntentReceiver.class);

}
```

while i compile the above code i am getting

```
e   03-19 16:13:35.455: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1247): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
03-19 16:13:35.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1247): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.XYZ}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
03-19 16:13:35.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2268)
03-19 16:13:35.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
03-19 16:13:35.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:112)
03-19 16:13:35.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1692)
03-19 16:13:35.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-19 16:13:35.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-19 16:13:35.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
03-19 16:13:35.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 16:13:35.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-19 16:13:35.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
03-19 16:13:35.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
03-19 16:13:35.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-19 16:13:35.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1247): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
03-19 16:13:35.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:281)
03-19 16:13:35.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at com.XYZ.onCreate(ManualUpdate.java:86)
03-19 16:13:35.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
03-19 16:13:35.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
```

Comment: Can you show some code? Are you able to see any register logs information? I'm using it in my latest app and it working alright.

Comment: i dint see any register log information.. can you pls give me a guidance.. I am trying this for more than 2days. i cant able to get proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add "airshipconfig.properties" file to assets with:

```
developmentAppKey = key
developmentAppSecret = key
productionAppKey = key
productionAppSecret = key
inProduction = true
transport = c2dm
c2dmSender = email
```

and remove the:

```
options.developmentAppKey = "My Key";
options.developmentAppSecret "My key";
```

from your code.

What about the AndroidManifest.xml? Did you set up it right?

```
       <!-- REQUIRED -->
    <receiver android:name="com.urbanairship.CoreReceiver">
        <!-- REQUIRED IntentFilter - For Helium and Hybrid -->
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- REQUIRED for C2DM and Hybrid -->
    <receiver android:name="com.urbanairship.push.c2dm.C2DMPushReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <!-- Receive the actual message -->
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
          <category android:name="com.XXXXXXXX" />
      </intent-filter>
      <!-- Receive the registration id -->
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
          <category android:name="com.XXXXXXXX" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- REQUIRED -->
    <!-- The 'android:process' parameter is optional. Set it to a value starting
        with a colon (:) to make it run in a separate,
        private process -->
    <service android:name="com.urbanairship.push.PushService"
            android:process=":com.urbanairship.push.process"/>

    <!-- OPTIONAL, if you want to receive push, push opened and registration completed intents -->
    <receiver android:name="com.XXXXXXXXXX.service.IntentReceiver" />
```

And remember that you should always see some logs information from UrbanAirShip. A specially registration information. Check also if your device was added to devices on urban website.

Comment: Yes, to see notifications. But you don'y need it to register your device. Remember also that Urban is not working always. Couple time I got issue to receive notifications, but it always register my device.

Comment: Getting error in UAirship.takeoff, so that i hve changed code to ' UAirship.takeOff((Application) this.getApplicationContext(), options);' is this rite..???

Comment: what should i give in manifest, in this line "category android:name="com.XXXXXXXX" can i give my own Activity..??

Comment: okay, How can we get appid from the above code..?? because while sending notification from UrbanAirship we have to specify appid rite.

Comment: i am getting error while compile the above source, i found in logcat {Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{MyOwnActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content}

Comment: You don't need to know appid of your device, try to send a broadcast.

Comment: okay.. i am getting following error while compile the source..  Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{MyOwnActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content

Comment: There is nothing in my main activity, from oncreate i put this code.

Comment: I resolved that issue, but even i dint receive the message from Airship.. do we register from device..??

Comment: Yes, what about the google account? Did you manage to setup c2md? you need an account set with your email to work.

Comment: i cant understand, can you pls explain me what you exactly saying. what should we register from device.??

Comment: Really I don't know why you got so many issues with UrbanAirShip, everything is on their website.

Comment: And what about C2DM Auth Token ?

Comment: UrbanAirShip is using google C2DM system to push notifications for android devices. I know that they using also something more, but don't remember right now. You need to set up an account on http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/signup.html and than get auth token to add it to your app on UrbanAirShip.

Comment: Yes added Autho in my urbanAirship, even that i cant receive any notification. dont know whats happening. if you have any sample code for urban Airship, can you pls send it to me.

Comment: I started from this test version: https://github.com/goodm/Push-Notifications but there is no properties file in assets.

Comment: you need a airshipconfig.properties file in assets folder. Look at my answer above.

Comment: in my property file i only given developmentAppKey and developmentAppSecret. i dint give productionAppKey = key
productionAppSecret = key and inProduction = true. is this okay.

Comment: Depends how did you set up the UrbanAirShip app. You can fill up also production and inProduction, with the same keys what developKeys, just for in case.

Answer (score 0):

For android & PhoneGap::

Create a xx.java in your src directory file that contains the following

```
package com.myapp.mobile.push.handler;
import com.phonegap.DroidGap;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import com.urbanairship.Logger;
import com.urbanairship.push.PushManager;
import com.urbanairship.push.PushPreferences;

public class extraFunctions  extends DroidGap {
    public WebView mAppView;
    private DroidGap mGap;
    public extraFunctions(DroidGap gap, WebView view)
     {
        mAppView = view;
        mGap = gap;
     }   

     public String getAUID(){
         PushPreferences prefs = PushManager.shared().getPreferences();
         return prefs.getPushId();
     }

}
```

To access it:
 in your assets/www

using javascript call: window.extraFunctions.getAUID();